# Issue Parsing Php With file_get_contents

Tags: php, dynamic

I'm loading my nav-bar from one php file, so I can just edit one file to update the whole site.

Code:

```
function getRsc($url){
    return file_get_contents($url.'.php');
}
```

That was working file until I tried to add actual php to the file.

```
  <?php
      if(isLoggedIn()){
        echo("<a class='btn btn-success' href='/account.php'> My Account </a>");
      }else {
        echo("<a class='btn btn-success' href='/login.php'> Login/Signup </a>");
      } 
  ?>
```

It just displays the PHP as text, not parsing it. How can I accomplish this? 
Thanks.

Comment: How are this two codes related ???

Comment: @Baba The second code block is part of the navigation bar file that I'm reading from.

Comment: Just use `include`.... (and unless you are using a webrequest / the long way around, php code is NOT parsed with file_get_contents, that is why we use `include` for local files).

Comment: Why you not use `include`?

Comment: That's how it works, you need to use include or require.

Comment: Even if you need the results in a variable rather than output immediately, you still need to include or require.  You just need to get a tiny bit tricky with output buffering to capture the results as a string.

Comment: file_get_contents won't parse the file unless you're calling it via http. Show us the line that has file_get_contents

Answer (score 4):

You can't `file_get_contents` a PHP file on the local file system like that. It won't get executed, you'll just get back the plain-text, unprocessed code.

You need `include` or `require` instead for a local PHP file.

Comment: And for your sake, I really hope there's no chance that `$url` can be set by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you just doing a regular `require`? e.g.,

```
<?php

require "path/to/nav-bar.php";
```

You're not supposed to use `file_get_contents` to load and run a PHP file. Take a look at [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).